# What did the Enterprise D (E?) do during the Dominion War?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-dominion

Pretty simple question. It doesn't seem like there's a whole lot of canon on the crew of the Enterprise during the Dominion War. Are their activities during the war ever brought up in canon?

I vaguely remember something mentioned during one of the movies very briefly about how exhausting the Dominion Wars have been. Maybe this was *First Contact*? But I don't think they were very specific.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One task the Enterprise E had was welcoming the [Evora](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Evora) into the Federation, as seen in *Insurrection*.

Other than that, the Enterprise was not largely active in the war.  It most likely was relegated to system defense in important systems and flag-showing missions to allies. ("See, you ARE important!  Would we send the Enterprise to protect you if you weren't?")

In-Universe, no explanation for this is given (though the presence of families aboard is a likely cause), though it should be noted that the ship was still very new.  It had a year-long shake-down cruise, which likely took up a significant part of the 2-year long war.

Out of universe, it was *DS9* 's show.  They weren't about to bring in a whole crew of special guest stars to be a deus ex machina.

Comment: Considering that would have meant bringing the _Enterprise_ in out of nowhere, I think you have your terms backwards.  The sudden appearance of the _Enterprise_ would have made it _machina ex deus_.

Comment: They probably just didn't want to pay the salaries for majority of TNG cast to just appear in a series of episodes.

Comment: @BBlake, they certainly didn't have any problems doing just that in voyager, or at least near enough.

Comment: Voyager needed more ratings help than DS9. And DS9 did get Michael Dorn as Worf after ST:Generations.

Comment: @Tango: LOL!  Very good point, but the correct Latin would be *machina ex deo* (after the preposition *ex* the noun *deus* must be declined in the ablative case, hence *deo*).

Comment: The graphic novel "Star Trek: Forgiveness" answered this very question. The Enterprise-E was largely used to take up the diplomatic slack, racing around the universe putting out diplomatic fires & holding the Federation together politically. It was a fact that Picard & Geordi both resented, as they would prefer to be fighting in the war and making a difference.

Comment: There is a book series about the Dominion War. Two of the books are about the DS9 series and the other two are about the TNG series Enterprise-E .

Comment: @Derek: I'm sure there are.  That said, *Star Trek* novels, unlike the previous (currently uncertain) state of *Star Wars* novels, have never been canon.

Comment: also, Picard was primarily a diplomat, not a combat commander

Answer (score 13):

The Enterprise E took part in the events of *First Contact* and *Insurrection* during the time period that Deep Space Nine was fighting the Dominion War.

> 2373 - The events of Star Trek: First Contact.
>
> 2373–2375 - The Dominion War is fought. [...]
>
> 2375 - The events of Star Trek: Insurrection. Dialogue in this film and in the DS9 finale "What You Leave Behind" place the chronology of this film as during that episode, after the final battle of the war but before the treaty signing ceremony. Most notable in the film is Worf's ability to leave the station to join the Enterprise, as well as a line about Federation diplomats being involved in Dominion negotiations, and the Federation's willingness to work with the Son'a, who are established as a Dominion ally during the war.

--[Timeline of Star Trek on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Star_Trek#23rd_century)

There are a number of quasi-canonical books that also cover this time period, particular between the start of the war and *Insurrection* (which occurs at its very end). You can read synopses [on Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28NCC-1701-E%29#2372-2373). Perhaps most notably, the Enterprise crew almost singlehandedly freed Betazed from the Dominion.

Comment: The events of first contact didn't take up any time in their timeline. The amount of time that lapsed all happened in the past. They came back to the present at the exact same point that they left. So this would not be an answer to the question of what they did for those two years.

Comment: The Enterprise-E probably needed at least a few weeks/months refit after the events of First Contact. Although the exterior of the ship was relatively untouched (apart from the main deflector) over half the ship had been over taken by the Borg, with who knows how many modifications made.

Answer (score 5):

The Enterprise-D was destroyed before the dominion war has started, hence why a statement similar to "Sorry about your ship" was made by Captain Sisko (S4:E1 - The Way of the Warrior). Enterprise-E was built during 2372 at San Francisco Fleet Yards.

It was never stated in an episode of *DS9* nor on *Memory Alpha* whether the Enterprise-E took a large part in the war however they did continue their duties of Diplomacy (Picard's speciality). In Star Trek: Insurrection, they were tasked with welcome to the Evora to the federation until a dispute began/nearby in the Briar Patch.

According to Memory Beta, they were part of the 16th fleet (was still a fleet before the Dominion War took place) with two well known vessels, the flagship Enterprise-E and Enterprise-D, possibly a reason why it was nicked name the "flagship fleet". The 16th fleet did have a battle against the Dominion.

Source: [http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-E)](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28NCC-1701-E%29)

Source: http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Starfleet_16th_Fleet

Answer (score 1):

http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28NCC-1701-E%29

Stardate: Unknown (early in 2372) During the Enterprise's shakedown cruise, Captain Morgan Bateson was temporarily assigned command. Shortly after assuming this position, he defied Starfleet orders in an effort to strike at the heart of the newly aggressive Klingon Empire; the ship was commandeered from his control and used against the Cardassian Union. The vessel was later recovered and transferred to the command of Captain Jean-Luc Picard. (TNG novel: Ship of the Line)

Not long afterward, the Enterprise engaged in a war games exercise with the USS Samson in the Pantera Nebula. During these exercises, the Samson was infiltrated and destroyed by a rogue Changeling, which then transferred aboard the Enterprise. Captain Picard and crew were eventually able to force it off the ship. (TNG - Slings and Arrows eBook: A Sea of Troubles)

Stardate: c. 49460 In the aftermath of the bombing of the Antwerp Conference in mid-2372, the Enterprise was charged with transporting a team of explosive experts to a number of key Starfleet facilities, including Deep Space 9 and Starbase 375. These experts discovered co-conspirators in Admiral James Leyton's attempted coup on Earth. One of these experts, Lieutenant Padraig Daniels, was offered the position of Enterprise chief of security. (TNG - Slings and Arrows eBook: The Oppressor's Wrong)

Stardate: 49710.1 Three months later, the Enterprise attended a security summit called by Admiral Jeremiah Hayes at Starbase 19. (TNG - Slings and Arrows eBook: The Insolence of Office)

Stardate: Unknown (late 2372) The Enterprise was struck by a mysterious epidemic while they were transporting an envoy from the planet Kendaray to a summit on Denobula Triaxa. (TNG - Slings and Arrows eBook: That Sleep of Death)

Stardate: Unknown (early 2373) The Enterprise was called to Earth by the newly inaugurated Federation President Min Zife. He charged Picard and Captain Benjamin Sisko with a mission that aimed to reopen negotiations with the Klingon Empire, which had withdrawn from the Khitomer Accords over a year earlier. (TNG - Slings and Arrows eBook: Enterprises of Great Pitch and Moment)

Stardate: 50368.0 The Enterprise was dispatched to the planet Chiaros IV in the desolate expanse known as the Geminus Gulf to prevent the region from falling under the control of the Romulan Star Empire. There, Captain Picard and Lieutenant Sean Hawk discovered the existence of the rogue Starfleet covert operations division known as Section 31. (TNG novel: Rogue)

Stardate 50893.5 While a Federation armada assembled to face a Borg attack in the Typhon Expanse, the Enterprise was assigned to patrol the Romulan Neutral Zone. In contravention of his orders, Picard ordered the ship to Earth, where it played an instrumental role in defeating the Borg attack. Immediately after blunting the main Borg assault, the Enterprise traveled to Earth's past to prevent the Borg from changing history. (TNG movie: Star Trek: First Contact; WizKids module: Tactics).

Stardate: Unknown (early in 2372) During the Enterprise's shakedown cruise, Captain Morgan Bateson was temporarily assigned command. Shortly after assuming this position, he defied Starfleet orders in an effort to strike at the heart of the newly aggressive Klingon Empire; the ship was commandeered from his control and used against the Cardassian Union. The vessel was later recovered and transferred to the command of Captain Jean-Luc Picard. (TNG novel: Ship of the Line)

Not long afterward, the Enterprise engaged in a war games exercise with the USS Samson in the Pantera Nebula. During these exercises, the Samson was infiltrated and destroyed by a rogue Changeling, which then transferred aboard the Enterprise. Captain Picard and crew were eventually able to force it off the ship. (TNG - Slings and Arrows eBook: A Sea of Troubles)

Stardate: c. 49460 In the aftermath of the bombing of the Antwerp Conference in mid-2372, the Enterprise was charged with transporting a team of explosive experts to a number of key Starfleet facilities, including Deep Space 9 and Starbase 375. These experts discovered co-conspirators in Admiral James Leyton's attempted coup on Earth. One of these experts, Lieutenant Padraig Daniels, was offered the position of Enterprise chief of security. (TNG - Slings and Arrows eBook: The Oppressor's Wrong)

Stardate: 49710.1 Three months later, the Enterprise attended a security summit called by Admiral Jeremiah Hayes at Starbase 19. (TNG - Slings and Arrows eBook: The Insolence of Office)

Stardate: Unknown (late 2372) The Enterprise was struck by a mysterious epidemic while they were transporting an envoy from the planet Kendaray to a summit on Denobula Triaxa. (TNG - Slings and Arrows eBook: That Sleep of Death)

Stardate: Unknown (early 2373) The Enterprise was called to Earth by the newly inaugurated Federation President Min Zife. He charged Picard and Captain Benjamin Sisko with a mission that aimed to reopen negotiations with the Klingon Empire, which had withdrawn from the Khitomer Accords over a year earlier. (TNG - Slings and Arrows eBook: Enterprises of Great Pitch and Moment)

Stardate: 50368.0 The Enterprise was dispatched to the planet Chiaros IV in the desolate expanse known as the Geminus Gulf to prevent the region from falling under the control of the Romulan Star Empire. There, Captain Picard and Lieutenant Sean Hawk discovered the existence of the rogue Starfleet covert operations division known as Section 31. (TNG novel: Rogue)
Battle001

The Enterprise engaging the Borg

Stardate 50893.5 While a Federation armada assembled to face a Borg attack in the Typhon Expanse, the Enterprise was assigned to patrol the Romulan Neutral Zone. In contravention of his orders, Picard ordered the ship to Earth, where it played an instrumental role in defeating the Borg attack. Immediately after blunting the main Borg assault, the Enterprise traveled to Earth's past to prevent the Borg from changing history. (TNG movie: Star Trek: First Contact; WizKids module: Tactics).

Stardate: c. 50910 Soon after, the Enterprise was assigned to patrol near sector 221G, home of the recently fallen Thallonian Empire. The ship's crew catalogued the terrible refugee situation caused by the failure of the Thallonian infrastructure. Shortly thereafter, Admiral Alynna Nechayev dispatched Picard and the Enterprise to convince former Starfleet officer Mackenzie Calhoun to return to Starfleet as captain of the USS Excalibur, assigned to assist the needy inhabitants of Sector 221-G. (NF novel: House of Cards)
2374-2375Edit

Stardate: 51405.9 The Enterprise was dispatched to investigate a mysterious incident in a lab on the planet Galor IV attempting to re-create the work of Commander Data's creator Noonien Soong. During the course of the investigation, Data unraveled a mystery that revealed much to him about the history of androids in the galaxy. (TNG novel: Immortal Coil)

tardate: 51701.3 The Enterprise was ordered to the homeworld of the Gorn, where Picard attempted to recruit the lizard-like race into joining in the war against the Dominion. (TNG comic: "The Gorn Crisis")

Stardate: Unknown (late 2374) The Enterprise was dispatched to Betazed to liberate the planet from the Dominion. Assisted by Commander Elias Vaughn of Starfleet Intelligence, Counselor Deanna Troi made some of the most difficult decisions of her life to save her home. (TNG novel: The Battle of Betazed)

Stardate: Unknown The Enterprise defended the Ba'ku people from the Son'a. (TNG movie: Star Trek: Insurrection)

Stardate: 52603.2 The Enterprise and the USS Columbia defended the Earth against an incursion by the Breen. (TNG short story: "Eleven Hours Out")

Comment: most of this is not canon but good work on detail and research. +1

Comment: There are parts of this entry that duplicate itself.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are they were just in another Fleet Group, probably leading a fleet that wasn't the Second, Fifth or Ninth Fleet, those featured in the retake of Deep Space Nine.  According to [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Starfleet_16th_Fleet) The Entrprise-D was in the 16th Fleet through 2370, which was tasked with Scientific and Diplomatic missions along the Romulan, Cardassian, and Klingon borders, but nothing Dominion war specific.  I would guess that if they were with the 16th during the war they would act as support for whatever Fleet Group needed them, becoming a mobile command and control center serving a similar purpose as [Starbase 375](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Starbase_375) for whatever Fleet Group they were a part of.

Comment: The Dominion War didn't start until 2373, after the Enterprise D was destroyed.

Comment: Oh, good point.  I doubt even with the E Picard would have changed fleets, since the 16th is focused on Science and Diplomacy.  But it would have been coming off the lines just as the Dominion war was beginning, so I suppose it could have been assigned elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have a novel where Picard and the others were somewhat involved in the Dominion Wars, but they were out and about some, fighting mostly Cardassians, and Picard eventually disguised himself as a Bajoran  (the Bajoran were sort of neutral in the novel but some got involved when the Cardassians attacked one of their worlds) to infiltrate the enemy territory when he learned that the Dominions had something secretive going on and they were using Federation prisoners for building a wormhole so the Dominions and Cardassians could invade Federation territory in full force and attack Earth (they also had the prisoners mine some material I forgot the name of from a black hole) and Picard helped the Bajorans  prevent that.